# Posting XML as request body to Java Rest in c#

Tags: c#, rest

I have application built with C# that consume Restful built with Java Expecting XML as request body.How do i go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Need more more information on what you are doing specifically what c# http stack you are using. It should not matter what the technology the service is written.

Here is one way you could accomplish this

1) Install HttpClient from Nuget. It's version 0.5.0.0

2) Use the following code

```
var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
var url = @"http://localhost:9999/books";

var content = new StringContent("<book><title>some title</title></book>", Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

client.Post(url, content);
```

HttpClient is very easy to use and can be discussed here http://wcf.codeplex.com